# Обработка NaN и Infinite при вычислении в Java

Tags: java

Есть метод для возведения числа в степень.

```
public static double raisedToPower(double a, double b) {
    return Math.pow(a, b);
}
```

В результате вычисления метод может возвратить значения NaN и Infinity, что в свою очередь может поломать программу в точке вызова.

В моем понимании я должен обработать это внутри метода (Если NaN или Infinity, то возвратить ключ, который можно обработать вне метода). Вот в чём вопрос, что можно возвратить в качестве ключа или есть другой способ обработать данную ситуацию?

```
public static double raisedToPower(double a, double b) {
    double res = Math.pow(a, b);
    if (Double.isNaN(res) || Double.isInfinite(res)) {
        return key;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом вы идею поняли верно, но интерпретировали неправильно.

NaN и Infitity - это уже и есть такой "ключ"

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую вызвать исключение и ловить его во вне:

```
if(Double.isNaN(res)){
  throw(new Exception("NAN"));
}
else if(Double.isInfinite(res)){
  throw(new Exception("INFINITE"));
}
```

Далее, в месте использования метода просто пишем обработчик исключения через try, catch, finally.