# Проверка на Nan и Infinity

Tags: java

При выводе отчета нужно убрать ячейки содержащие значения Nan и Infinity, оставить только double.
Мой вариант не работает. Я сделал проверку через Double.parseDouble, но это не сработало.

Как можно при проверке строки, является ли она числом, устранить Nan и Infinity?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525095/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-nan-%D0%B8-infinite-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java?rq=1

Comment: Использовать библиотеку apache StringUtils.isNaN(arg)